# How to set default installation directory with a constant directory name in Install4j?

Tags: java, install4j

We are using Intall4j (6.1.6) and we have a problem on the uninstall phase when a user tries install our product's components not inside a directory.
When this scenario happens (e.g. the user installed the product on `C:\Program Files` and not in a custom directory like `C:\Program Files\MyApp`) - the uninstall phase will try to delete *Program Files* too. this happens due to a configuration we added to make sure all components are delete properly (also include some temp files and the parent directory).

Our installation run both on Windows & Linux and each environment has it own default installation directory. What I would have want is the ability to set (better say - 'force') a constant directory to each default installation directory (which the user cannot change while the installation - e.g. - no matter where you install it, it always be inside 'MyApp' directory), so if by any chance anyone installs the product not inside a directory the uninstall phase won't delete the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

First, even if the user installs into `C:\Program Files\` directly, the uninstaller will not delete all files in that directory - only the files that were created by the installer.

For forcing a particular directory structure use the "Validation script" property of the "Installation location" screen, for example:

```
if (file.equals(WinFileSystem.getProgramFilesDirectory())) {
    Util.showWarningMessage(
      "This directory is not allowed as an installation directory");
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```